# Hide menus contributed by other plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My eclipse rcp application depends on a set of eclipse plugins, after I add them as dependency, the "Run" and "Search" menu appear in the main menu bar.

Which plugin contains these two menu contribution ?

How Can I hide the menu, while I still need the plugin which contribute the menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use activities and contexts, [as described in the Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_scalability.htm)

Answer (score 1):

> Which plugin contains these two menu contribution ?

You can use Shift-Alt-F2 and then click the menu (inside your IDE, not your RCP app) to find out the menu id and thereby get a good idea of which plugin contributes it.